# ffmpeg "moov atom not found" when merging MP4 & MKV

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I am trying to merge an MP4 file (which contains only video), with a MKV file (which contains only audio). I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55b524bcb9c0] moov atom not found
file:///home/myuser/output.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Why is that?

---

Version of `ffmpeg`: 3.3.4-2

System: Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: What version of `ffmpeg` are you using? Also, on what system?

Comment: @Vlastimil 3.3.4-2 on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: What happens if you use the output container MKV instead of MP4?

Comment: Have you tried this: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy muxed.mp4`?

Comment: In any case, please post full output of `mediainfo` on both of those files for us to see details.

Comment: http://muzso.hu/2012/11/14/how-to-fix-a-broken-mp4-mov-video-ffmpeg-reports-moov-atom-not-found